# Redirect attributes not showing error message on front end (Springboot + Thyemeleaf)

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Whatever be the condition (success/duplicate/failed) only the success message is shown on the frontend. Even if I execute a duplicate data, only the success message is displayed.

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/add-category")
public String add(@ModelAttribute("categoryNew") Category category, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
    try {

        categoryService.save(category);

        attributes.addFlashAttribute("success", "Added successfully");
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("duplicate", "Duplicate entry not possible");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Duplicate");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("failed", "Error server");
    }
    return "redirect:/categories";
}
```

HTML Snippet in Categories.html:

```
<div class="mb-3"></div>

<div th:if = "${success}" class="text-center alert alert-success">
    <p th:text="${success}"></p>
</div>

<div th:if = "${failed}" class="text-center alert alert-danger">
    <p th:text="${failed}"></p>
</div>

<div th:if = "${duplicate}" class="text-center alert alert-danger">
    <p th:text="${duplicate}"></p>
</div>
```

I was trying to show the error message of "duplicate". But only the success message is showing up.

Comment: it would be good to share the code for handling the endpoint `/categories`.